# What's the use of SDK Manager - as the same seems to be possible with build.gradle

Tags: android

What are the use cases in Android Studio when one would neeed, or would be better off, using the **SDK Manager**, as opposed to specifying dependencies in the **build.gradle** and letting the gradle to download things as needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are two different things. Gradle resolves dependencies related to your project/module/app. 
The SDK manager manages parts of your development environment, like the build tools, platforms and extras like support repositories.

For example, in your build.gradle specifiy

```
compileSdkVersion 16
```

If you haven't installed the lvl 16 platform files, your app won't compile. Gradle will *ask* you to download them via the SDK manager, but not download them for you.

On the other hand of course, the SDK manager will not resolve dependencies for your app.

Comment: The SDK Manager has, say, Google Play services, and gradle can download them, too. So, some of the components can be accessed both ways?

Comment: Google play services is a little bit special. As far as I understand, the SDK manager provides the resource from which gradle then adds the play services to your project. Gradle will complain if you havent installed the Google Play services repository in the SDK manager.

Comment: Agreed. The Gradle for Android plugin automatically adds the "Android Repository" and "Google Repository" to the search locations for dependencies, if and only if you have downloaded those things to your hard drive via the SDK Manager.